# What is an "ephod" and what is its meaning?

Tags: symbolism

In many episodes of the Judges, Samuel and other books, the "ephod" is referenced as the symbol of religious and civil power.

However, what is an "ephod", exactly? What is its meaning? Who could wear it?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Related: In modern Hebrew, ephod (Hebrew: אֵפוֹד) means a vest, like those worn by photographers, soldiers etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> An ephod (Hebrew: אֵפוֹד ʾēfōḏ; /ˈɛfɒd/ or /ˈiːfɒd/) was a type of apron, which according to the Hebrew Bible, was worn by the Jewish high priest the kohen gadol, an artifact and an object to be revered in ancient Israelite culture, and was closely connected with oracular practices and priestly ritual.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephod)

[image]
[Ephod](https://raykliu.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/ephod/)

Comment: Excellent illustration and +1 for the article pointing out that the word ephod is also used as a covering of gold overlying a statue (Judges 8:27, 17:5, 18:14, 17, 18, 20). This was an idolatrous practice and has nothing to do with the original ephod.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://www.gotquestions.org/ephod.html) is about the ephod as worn by the High Priest, part of which says this:

> As a garment the ephod is referred to in the priestly ordinances as a part of the official dress of the high priest. It was to be made of threads “of blue and of purple, of scarlet, and fine twined linen” and embroidered in gold thread “with cunning work” (Exodus 28:4; 29:5; 39:2; Leviticus 8:7).

> The ephod was held together by a girdle of similar workmanship sewed on to it. It had two shoulder pieces, which, as the name implies, crossed the shoulders, and were apparently fastened or sewed to the ephod in front. In dressing, the shoulder pieces were joined in the back to the two ends of the ephod. Nothing is said of the length of the garment. At the point where the shoulder pieces were joined together in the front “above the girdle,” two golden rings were sewed on, to which the breastplate was attached.

The article also explains how there is an entirely different meaning of the word ephod as used in idolatrous worship:

> In Judges 8:26–27 it is recorded that Gideon took from the Ishmaelites, who were Midianite allies, golden earrings, weighing 1,700 shekels of gold, and made an “ephod thereof, and put it in his city, even in Ophrah,” where it was worshiped by all Israel. In Judges 17:5, Micah made an ephod and teraphim, or idol, for his sanctuary. The most natural inference from all these passages is that “ephod” here signifies an image that was set up in the sanctuary, especially since the word is cited with teraphim, which undoubtedly refers to graven images (Hosea 3:4). The conclusion is that ephod, in these cases, refers to a portable idol. Some scholars have suggested that the connection between the idol and the garment is that the idol was originally clothed in a linen garment, and the term ephod gradually came to describe the idol as a whole.

Comment: +1 -- important distinction between the vestment and the item used in divination. However, the second meaning was not always idolatrous. https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5790-ephod

Answer (score 3):

In Judges and Samuel, the ephod is a priestly garment symbolizing the high priest's authority (as in the Torah) and a symbol of idolatrous civil power. It is important to know, however, that the ephod, even when it was more than merely a priestly garment, did not necessarily involve idolatry. Rather, it could sometimes be used for an approved form of divination through yes-or-no questions involving [urim and thummin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urim_and_Thummim). For example, 1 Sam. 21:

> 9 When David learned that Saul was plotting evil against him, he said
> to the priest Abiathar, “Bring the ephod here.” 10 David said, “O
> Lord, the God of Israel... will
> Saul come down as your servant has heard?” ...The Lord said, “He will
> come down.” 12 Then David said, “Will the men of Keilah surrender me
> and my men into the hand of Saul?” The Lord said, “They will surrender
> you.”

It appears that "ephod" may have also referred specifically to the breastplate associated with it. This was the case of with the ephod of Gideon

Judges 8:26-27:

> The weight of the golden earrings that he requested was one thousand
> seven hundred shekels of gold... Gideon made an ephod of it and put it
> in his town, in Ophrah, and all Israel prostituted themselves to it
> there, and it became a snare to Gideon and to his family.

This ephod became an object of idolatrous worship, but the ephod was not an idol in itself. In the case of the ephod mentioned in Judges 17-18, the text does not say that it was worshiped, but it did become part of a unauthorized shrine at Dan.

**Summary**: "Ephod" refers to a priestly garment and/or breastplate sometimes used for divination to ascertain the will of God. It usually symbolized the authority of the high priest. In at least one case it also became an symbol of civil power and an object of idolatry.